# slick, несколько слайдеров с тем же классом?

Tags: javascript, slick.js

есть 6 табов, и в каждом табе свой слайдер. Создал одинаковую структуру и дал для каждого слайдер один и тот же класс который потом в js привязал к slick

Т.е

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </div>
</div>




$('.slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

Но при переключение табов слайдер работает с ошибкой, не показывает сразу пока не поменяю слайд
и такая ошибка при смене таба

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null
```

Я думаю что несколько слайдеров надо по другому назначать, не подскажите как?

Comment: Вроде все работает с табами. https://codepen.io/DuudeXX8/pen/NWKRypx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант решения

```
    $('.slider').each(function() {
        $(this).slick({
            slidesToShow: 4,
            dots: false,
            arrows: false,
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Работает, но при добавлении appendDots работает некорректно. все точки выводятся под первым табом.

```
$('.slider').each(function() {
    $(this).slick({
        dots: true,
        appendDots: $('.slider-dots'),
    });
});
```

Оказывается надо добавить appendDots: $(this).siblings('.slider-dots'),